# Подскажите, как правильно работать с SQLite под Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, архитектура

Про ORM слышал, но пока хочу обойтись без них.
Встречал такой способ работы, когда в классе унаследованном от SQLiteOpenHelper, в статических строках описывается структура базы данных. Примерно так:

```
public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reminder_database";

    public static final String TASKS_TABLE = "tasks_table";

    public static final String TASK_TITLE_COLUMN = "task_title";
    public static final String TASK_DATE_COLUMN = "task_date";
    public static final String TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN = "task_priority";
    public static final String TASK_STATUS_COLUMN = "task_status";
    public static final String TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN = "task_time_stamp";

    private static final String TASKS_TABLE_CREATE_SCRIPT =  "CREATE TABLE "
            + TASKS_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TASK_TITLE_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + TASK_DATE_COLUMN + " LONG, " + TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN + " INTEGER, "
            + TASK_STATUS_COLUMN + " INTEGER, " + TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN + " LONG);";


    public static final String SELECTION_STATUS = DBHelper.TASK_STATUS_COLUMN + " = ?";

    private DBQueryManager queryManager;
    private DBUpdateManager updateManager;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        queryManager = new DBQueryManager(getReadableDatabase());
        updateManager = new DBUpdateManager(getWritableDatabase());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TASKS_TABLE_CREATE_SCRIPT);
    }
```

Но такой подход мне не нравится.
Решил описать структуру таблицы в виде XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    version = "1">
    <table name = "tasks_table">
        <column name = "_id"                type = "INTEGER"    property = "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"/>
        <column name = "task_title"         type = "TEXT"       property = "NOT NULL"/>
        <column name = "task_date"          type = "LONG"       property = ""/>
        <column name = "task_priority"      type = "INTEGER"    property = ""/>
        <column name = "task_status"        type = "INTEGER"    property = ""/>
        <column name = "task_time_stamp"    type = "LONG"       property = ""/>        
    </table>
</database>
```

А затем уже напишу класс, который будет работать с таблицей пользуясь только информацией из XML. Например, скрипт по созданию таблицы очень просто сгенерировать по этим данным.

Скажите пожалуйста, насколько такой подход правильный? На какие грабли я могу наткнуться в будущем? Применяется ли такой подход вообще при разработке? На что похож этот велосипед?

Comment: А в чем существенная разница между описанием костант и написанием xml? Я например когда нужно работать с SQLite просто создаю классы для каждой таблици а в SQLiteOpenHelper потом вызываю методы изэтих классов  onCreate  и onUpgrade

Comment: А можно пример кода, с таким подходом?

Comment: Хотя, наверное торможу. Это же и есть приведенный у меня в вопросе подход. Просто на каждую таблицу будет свой DBHelper.

Comment: нет,  DBHelper, но в из него будут вызываться методы из классов таблиц. Но существенно ничего не меняеться, кроме того что у вас каждая таблица в отдельном классе  и DBHelper нету кучи констант и другого кода

Comment: Если приведенный XML не получен откуда-то ранее или , например, не сгенерирован автоматически, то такой подход конечно можно использовать, но он не дает никаких преимуществ, даже наоборот - увеличивает и усложняет код. Я просто не вижу смысла в этом, так как никакого выигрыша, по сравнению с "классическим", такой подход не дает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код не претендует на правильное решение, просто пример!

**OptionsTable.java**

```
public class OptionsTable {

    // Database table
    public static final String TABLE_OPTIONS = "table_options";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_DB_VERSION = "db_version";



    // Database creation SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table "
                    + TABLE_OPTIONS
                    + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + COLUMN_DB_VERSION + " text "
                    + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
                                 int newVersion) {
        Log.w(PacketTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_OPTIONS);
        onCreate(database);
    }

}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "application.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        OptionsTable.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        OptionsTable.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```